# Regular expressions : How to exclude specific string inside a line

Tags: regex, sumologic

I'm trying to filter out API call names using regex.
The problem is that I can't filter out specific strings from the API calls which I don't need.

In the following examples I need to filter out/cut from the API call which contains the string **"sg-"** (if exists) what comes after it including the string itself and the others leave untouched.

Here is the example:

```
GET /api/cloudsecuritygroup/sg-91f988f7/history - 443  
GET /api/cloudsecuritygroup/sg-30333554 - 443  
GET /api/cloudaccounts/secret - 443  
GET /api/audit/event-types - 443  
GET /api/user/me/iam-safe/devices - 443
```

The result should look like this:

```
cloudsecuritygroup  
cloudsecuritygroup  
cloudaccounts/secret  
audit/event-types  
user/me/iam-safe/devices
```

Comment: You just want to check one link with your regex right?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is fetch the name of the API call using regex.

Comment: Ok, but for example `audit/event-types` does not contain `sg-`. So why is it in the result too? Or could you please give a bit more specifications on how it should work? And what did you try so far?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using SumoLogic to parse IIS logs.
The reason I've provided the other examples is because I want to exclude any characters which comes after "sg-" and for the other patters which don't contain "sg-" I want them not to be affected of this filter.
Basically, I'm running a search in SumoLogic and I want to parse the IIS logs and fetch the name of the API call using parse regex function.

I was able to achieve it but the API calls which contain "sg-" were written like this : cloudsecuritygroup/sg-  
And that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is `regex` you are looking for:

```
(?<=GET \/api)(.+(?=\/sg-)|[^\s]+)
```

Check it out [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/v4PvHj/1)